# Changing Spacing of Individual List Elements

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm attempting to create a simple single-page website, however I'm having problems with spacing in the navbar (as seen below).

[image]

Using an un-ordered list works fine until the list ends up behind the central logo. Using the current code adding an empty list creates too big a gap. Is it possible to change the spacing of individual list elements?

```css
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 11.5vh;
  width: 100vw;
  /* background-color: #07470B; */
  /* opacity: 0.96; */
  background: #f6f6f6;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 5vw;
  padding-top: 3vh;
}
.navbarList {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14vw;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-size: 5vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.navbarList li {
  margin: 0;
}
.navbarList a {
  color:#989898;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navbarList a:hover{
  color: #e68935;
}
```

```html
<body id="site">
<a href="#page1" class="smoothScroll"><img id="logoTop" src="images/logoHead.png"></a>
<div id="site">
  <div class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <!-- <li class="navbarList">
        <a href="#page1" class="smoothScroll">HOME</a>
      </li> -->
      <li class="navbarList">
          <a href="#divEndPage1" class="smoothScroll">ABOUT</a>
      </li>
      <!--<li class="navbarList"></li>-->
      <li class="navbarList">
          <a href="#page3" class="smoothScroll">EVENTS</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbarList">
          <a href="#page4" class="smoothScroll">GALLERY</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbarList"></li>
      <li class="navbarList">
        CONTACT
      </li>
      <li class="navbarList">
        CONTACT
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="navbarUnderline"></div>
  </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For the logo: use `position:absolute` and a higher `z-index` in the logo.
- For the list: don't use fixed `width` use `padding` instead

IDs(`#`) **must be** unique.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
  margin: 0
}
#main {
  position: relative
}
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 12vh;
  width: 100vw;
  /* background-color: #07470B; */
  /* opacity: 0.96; */
  background: #f6f6f6;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 5vw;
  padding-top: 3vh;
}
.navbarList {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-size: 3vw;
  padding: 2vh 2vw;
}
.navbarList li {
  margin: 0;
}
.navbarList a {
  color: #989898;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navbarList a:hover {
  color: #e68935;
}
#logoTop {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2vh;
  left: 55%;
  z-index: 11
}
```

```html
<body id="site">
  <div id="main">
    <a id="logoTop" href="#page1" class="smoothScroll">
      <img src="//lorempixel.com/30/20">
    </a>
    <div class="navbar">
      <ul>
        <!-- <li class="navbarList">
        <a href="#page1" class="smoothScroll">HOME</a>
      </li> -->
        <li class="navbarList">
          <a href="#divEndPage1" class="smoothScroll">ABOUT</a>
        </li>
        <!--<li class="navbarList"></li>-->
        <li class="navbarList">
          <a href="#page3" class="smoothScroll">EVENTS</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbarList">
          <a href="#page4" class="smoothScroll">GALLERY</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbarList"></li>
        <li class="navbarList">
          CONTACT
        </li>
        <li class="navbarList">
          CONTACT
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div id="navbarUnderline"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Completely new to web design so I'm a bit all over the place at the minute :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to adjust the spacing individually depending on the item, you can add an id and assign it CSS properties (padding, margin, etc...).
You can also use pseudo class in CSS as "nth-child(x)" or "nth-of-type(x)" to target a particular item.

Some advice on your code : to create your menu use the tag 'nav' instead of your 'div' "navbar". Also instead of using your class "navbarList" you assign to each "li" it's better to add a class to your 'ul' and then target the 'li' in CSS like this: ".classOfTheUl li". This target each 'li' of your 'ul' list with the class "classOfTheUl".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm a reviewer here and have a couple suggestions that could make your answer more readable. First, your answer might be more clear if you included a code snippet of your proposed solution instead of describing the code in text. Also, inline code snippets should have backticks around them instead of quotes to differentiate them as code. Here's some reference material: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code. Just a couple suggestions. Thanks for posting, and cheers!

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! I wasn't 100% if using nav would cause any problems in browsers which don't support html5. The site is for a generally elderly population so I'm expecting not brand new browsers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to separate them like you're trying to do, I might suggest using two separate unordered lists absolutely positioned on either side of the logo. Here is my basic mockup. You could adjust the number of list items on either side as needed.

HTML

```
    <ul class="left-nav">
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="logo-block"></div>

    <ul class="right-nav">
      <li>Four</li>
      <li>Five</li>
    </ul>
```

CSS

```
  ul {
    padding: 0;
  }

  li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 20px;
  }

  .logo-block {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -20px;
    background-color: red;
  }

  ul.left-nav {
    position: absolute;
    right: calc(50% + 20px);
  }

  ul.right-nav {
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% + 20px);
  }
```

[Here is a link to a mockup on CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gMMQWZ).